# Realm: updating objects with the same primary keys in an array

Tags: android, json, nosql, realm

I have an Invoice array that includes objects from Products array and I'm trying to update each Invoice array object independently, but when I update one object's property, all other objects' properties change.

For instance, In my first invoice I add 2 pens to the list, then in the second invoice, I add one pen, but after adding the second invoice, the count property of the first invoice also changes to 1.

How can I update one of them without affecting the other?

```js
// First Invoice
[
  {"date":0,"id":1,"products":
    [
      {"count":"2","format":"","id":"6921738073439","name":"pen","price":"15"}
    ]
  }
]


// Second Invoice
[
  {"date":0,"id":1,"products":
    [
      {"count":"1","format":"","id":"6921738073439","name":"pen","price":"15"}
    ]
  },
  {"date":0,"id":1,"products":
    [
      {"count":"1","format":"","id":"6921738073439","name":"pen","price":"15"}
    ]
  }
]
```

UPDATE: I've also included my java code of how I'm creating the invoice:

```
  public void save(final Invoice object) {
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) { 
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate((Invoice) object);
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.i("***", "success");
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                Log.i("***", error.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: please send your code for changing objects here , thanks

Comment: well yeah every invoice seems to have the same ID, what do you expect?

Comment: I want to copy an object to an array with different values what should i do ??